# GCP: select query with unnest from array has very big process data to run compared to hardcoded values

Tags: sql, arrays, select, process, google-bigquery

In bigQuery GCP, I am trying to grab some data in a table where the date is the same as a date in a list of values I have got. If I hardcode the list of values in the select it is vastly cheaper in process to run than if I use a temp structure like an array... 
Is there a way to use the temp structure but avoid the enormous processing cost ?
Why is it so expensive for something small simple like this.
please see below examples:

```
**-----1/ array structure example: this query process's 144.8 GB----------**  

WITH
 get_a as (
SELECT
GENERATE_DATE_ARRAY('2000-01-01','2000-01-02') as array_of_dates
)

SELECT
 a.heading as title
 a.ingest_time as proc_date
FROM
 'veiw_a.events' as a
 get_a as b
UNNEST(b.array_of_dates) as c
WHERE
 c in (CAST(a.ingest_time AS DATE)
 )

**------2/ hardcoded example: this query processes 936.5 MB over 154 X's less ? --------**
SELECT
 a.heading as title
 a.ingest_time as proc_date
FROM
 'veiw_a.events' as a
WHERE
 (CAST(a.ingest_time as DATE)) IN ('2000-01-01','2000-01-02')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably, your `view_a.events` table is partitioned by the `ingest_time`.

The issue is that partition pruning is very conservative (buggy?).  With the direct comparisons, BigQuery is smart enough to recognize exactly which partitions are used for the query.  But with the generated version, BigQuery is not able to figure this out, so the entire table needs to be read.